# How can I make an image become invisible and un- interactable on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a JavaScript script which will scan through a webpage for all of the *.gif* files and set their visibility properties to "hidden". This allows me to select what type of image I want to show on my page... I used this code:

```
function makeAllGIF(){
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(i = 0 ; i < x.length; i++){
        var y = x.item(i);
        if(y.getAttribute("src").match("gif") != null){
            y.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        else{
            y.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
}
```

---

Changing the code to

```
function makeAllGIF(){
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(i = 0 ; i < x.length; i++){
        var y = x.item(i);
        if(y.getAttribute("src").match("gif") != null){
            y.style.display = "normal";
        }
        else{
            y.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

works fine.

Comment: Use `display:none` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the attribute `display: none` on your images.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, [Levib is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663044/how-can-i-make-an-image-become-invisible-and-un-interactable-on-a-webpage/13663049#13663049) right. Just modify the code as below:

```
function makeAllGIF(){
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(i = 0 ; i < x.length; i++){
        var y = x.item(i);
        if(y.getAttribute("src").match("gif") != null){
            y.style.visibility = "visible";
            y.style.display = ""; // You can assign "block" as the value here.
        }
        else{
            y.style.visibility = "hidden";
            y.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```